# Play Framework with Ebean and PostgreSQL on localhost

Tags: postgresql, playframework-2.0, ebean

i'm new with Play-Framework, Ebeans and PostgreSQL and tried to find the right answer for days, but finally i didn't find any good solution for my problem. Maybe it is a noob-problem but for me would be important to know what i did wrong and get a right solution for my question. This would really really helps me a lot. The thing is that i always got this Error-Message when i start the localhost to get the values from the DB on "*localhost/9000/users*"

**Execution exception**

*[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ERROR: relation "users" does not exist Position: 61 Bind values:[] Query was: select t0.user_id as c0, t0.name as c1, t0.email as c2 from "users" t0 ]
In /.../app/controllers/Application.java at line 12.*

```
9    public class Application extends Controller {
10     
11       public static Result getAllUsers(){
12         return ok(Json.toJson(users.find.all()));
13       }
14        
15    }
```

So,
i have a PostgreSQL-DB running on localhost. 
I'm using instead of public-schemata my own schemata named "*test_schema*".
I also created a table named "*users*" with three attributes (user_ID, name, email).

I use Play Framework 2.3.0. and configured the /application.conf like this:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db"
db.default.schema=test_schema
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password="12345"
db.default.logStatements=true

evolutionplugin=disabled

ebean.default="models.*"
```

I disabled the evolution because the DB already exists and has also some entries.

So i created the Entity-Class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"users\"")
public class users extends Model{

public users(int user_ID, String name, String email){
    this.user_ID = user_ID;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email; 
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int user_ID;

@Required
private String name;

@Required
private String email;

public static Finder<Integer, users> find = new Finder<Integer, users>(Integer.class, users.class);


public static List<users> all() {
    return find.all();
}


public int getUserID() {
    return user_ID;
}

public void setUserID(int userID) {
    this.user_ID = userID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

In my Controller-Class i only have this method:

```
public static Result getAllUsers(){
   return ok(Json.toJson(users.find.all()));
```

}

And the conf/routes has this entry:

```
GET     /users                          controllers.Application.getAllUsers()
```

**What could be the reason for? Are their any suggestions to make it work?**

Comment: it'd be really good to highlight your question at the beginning too.

Comment: The Problem was that the DB got a table named "user_ID". Which makes problem with Ebean and the lower-case system behind. All tabels should be named with lower-case!

Comment: You really should respect basic Java conventions. Rename your class `User`, rename `user_ID` to `userId`. If the column is `user_ID` in your table and you can't change it, add `@Column(name = "user_ID")` to your property in the class.